# CKEditor command on new instance not working

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have the problem that `execCommand()` does not work immediately after creating the editor

```
var editor;

function1() {
  editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo('data', config);
  editor.execCommand('maximize'); // does not work
}

function2() {
  editor.execCommand('maximize'); // works
}
```

If I call `function2` after function1 it works.
What do I miss or not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor loads asynchronously; it won't exec your actions until it's ready. Use [`editor#instanceReady`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-instanceReady) event listener:

```
config.on = {
    'instanceReady': function( evt ) {
        this.execCommand('maximize');
    }
};
```

Comment: Good explanation, I got it!